# Object has no method '__super__'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I extends mongoose save function:

User Schema is:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema    = mongoose.Schema,
ObjectId    = Schema.ObjectId;

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Name: String,
  Surname: String,
  login:   {type: String, required: true},
  Password:  {type: String, required: true},
  email: { type: String, index: { unique: true } },
  Age: Number
});
```

And extended method is:

```
UserSchema.methods.save = function(okFn, failedFn) {
  if (this.isValid()) {
    this.__super__(okFn);
  } else {
    failedFn();
  }
};
```

And on 'save' try it gives me error:

```
TypeError: Object { object fields and values } has no method '__super__'
```

Comment: Where do you define __super__? __super__ is not a  standard javascript function. I know that backbone.js defines it but since you don't use it there is not way it can work. And what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeLeclerc we didn't define __super__ at all. It was an example taken out of context of tutorial. I try to figure it out later.
Thanks